# Want KVM/QEMU version 5 for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

A few weeks ago [KVM/QEMU version 5](https://www.qemu.org/2020/04/29/qemu-5-0-0/) came out. However, it's not bundled in the [5.4 kernel](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-kernel-5-4-whats-new-with-ubuntu-20-04-lts) of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as far as I know. I would like to set up a new virtualization host using Ubuntu 20.04 and KVM/QEMU 5.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I don't want to use 4.2.x since I think it has a networking bug.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions - qemu 5.0, libvirt 6.6, virtmanager 3.0, are available for Ubuntu 20.04:

- [https://launchpad.net/~jacob/+archive/ubuntu/virtualisation?field.series_filter=focal](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejacob/+archive/ubuntu/virtualisation?field.series_filter=focal)

You can also search the ppa repos for qemu.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [canonical-server backports repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-server/+archive/ubuntu/server-backports/):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-server/server-backports
```

Comment: i tried this with my Ubuntu Studio 20.04 to upgrade my old qemu installation vom 4.2 to 6.0. It worked without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

qemu 5.0-5 was [accepted into Debian Unstable](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/qemu) on May 13. 2020.

This means that it will be merged into Ubuntu 20.10 (not 20.04) sometime during the next few months.

- You can try pulling the 5.0 package from Debian and see if it will run in Ubuntu 20.04. It might, it might not.
- After the package is imported, you can run 5.0 in the pre-release version of Ubuntu 20.10. It's pre-release, so you are agreeing to be a tester. Note that we don't provide support here for 20.10 until after it's released.

Comment: Also note that if you go with the pre-release Ubuntu 20.10 you won't get any help here, as it will be off-topic in this site until it is released and become official.

Comment: 5.0 wasn't released in time for Ubuntu 20.04 and the SRU policy allows only fixes but not backports into the main archive. But when 20.10 is released there will also be backports of virtualization components available via https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OpenStack/CloudArchive